# combine 2 query into 1 query sql

Tags: sql

I have 2 SQL statements

```
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT COUNT(CodeAll) AS Total, CodeAll, Description,
LEFT(CodeAll, 1) AS Code
FROM Data WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2013/03/01 00:00:00' AND '2013/03/01 23:59:00'
AND (CodeAll Is Not Null)
GROUP BY CodeAll, Description ORDER BY Code
ASC
```

Results:

```
 Total | CodeAll | Description | Code
 -------------------------------------
  3       1c         Test          1
  3       1b         Test2         1
 10      1a         Test3         1
  2       2a          Test4        2
  5       2b         Test5         2
  5       3a         Test6         3
  3       3b         Test7         3
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT COUNT(CodeAll) AS SumCall, LEFT(CodeAll, 1) AS Code FROM Data 
WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2013/03/01 00:00:00' AND '2013/03/01 23:59:00' 
AND (CodeAll Is Not   Null) GROUP BY LEFT(CodeAll, 1)`
```

Results:

```
SumCall| Code 
16       1
7        2
8        3
```

I want to combine the 2 query into 1 query to produce:

```
 Total | CodeAll | Description | Code | SUM  | Percentage
 ---------------------------------------------------------
    3       1c         Test          1       16    18.75 %
    3       1b         Test2         1       16    18.75 %
   10      1a         Test3         1       16    62.5 % 
    2       2a          Test4        2        7    28.57 %
    5       2b         Test5         2        7    71.43 %
    5       3a         Test6         3        8    62.5 %
    3       3b         Test7         3        8    37.5 %
```

Query??

Please help

Comment: how mr shahid iqbal..

Comment: Percentage of Which column???

Comment: How u calculated Percentage?

Comment: calculated percentage. for example= 3*100/16

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```
SELECT      TOP 100 PERCENT COUNT(d1.CodeAll) AS Total,
            d1.CodeAll,d1.Description,LEFT(d1.CodeAll, 1) AS Code ,
            COUNT(d2.CodeAll) AS SumCall, (UrPercentageColumn + '%') as Percentage
FROM        data d1
INNER JOIN  data d2
ON          LEFT(d1.CodeAll, 1) = LEFT(d2.CodeAll, 1)
WHERE       DATE BETWEEN '2013/03/01 00:00:00' 
AND         '2013/03/01 23:59:00' 
AND         (CodeAll Is Not Null) 
GROUP BY    LEFT(CodeAll, 1),CodeAll, Description ORDER BY Code ASC
```

Comment: Mr shahid Iqbal column percentage calculated, for example : 3*100/16

Comment: i run,but show message error Ambiguous column name 'DATE'.

Comment: @rian: solve that dude thats not a big problem

Comment: @photon : the result query work,but column sumcal = total, i want column sumcall is count total by code